# Did the Russell Tribunal on War Crimes in Vietnam attempt to hold a session in the USA?

Tags: international

In the postscript of his book, *War Crimes in Vietnam*, Bertrand Russell called for an international tribunal to be held along the lines of the Nuremberg trials to charge the USA with war crimes that he said, had not the USA been a war time ally, been akin to that of Nazi Germany. He noted the resemblance several times during his book.

In fact, he had already been working on an ex-officio body already: such a tribunal had already been constituted in 1966 and had held hearings in Stockholm, Sweden and Roskilde, Denmark in 1967. They had, however, no official legal standing - hence presumably Russell's call for such a tribunal with official legal standing and which would be - given the gravity and scale of the crimes committed - have standing in international law, that is the law between nations (and not within, say, some particular nation).

**Q. Was Russell's call instrumental in helping to set up the International Criminal Court at The Hague?**

According to Zanfredi, a legal scholar:

> Sartre began his assessment of whether the United States could be considered as committing genocide in Vietnam by addressing the question of 'genocidal intent' and making reference to article 2 of the 1948 Convention on the Prevention and Punishment of Genocide.

He also adds that this language is reproduced almost verbatim in all statutes establishing and governing international criminal tribunals with jurisdiction over the crime of genocide.

Zanfredi also adds that both the legal and theoretical dimensions of the initial tribunal has been 'under-appreciated.' Particularly (and perhaps unsurprisingly in the US) with honourable exceptions such as Andrew Byrnes and Gabrielle Simms in their article on *People Tribunal, International Law and the Use of Force*, published in the USNW Law Journal.

Hence my question.

The historian Harish Mehta has noted that there was an extensive US media campaign at the time designed to discredit the tribunal. But the tribunal 'succeeded in its goal of impacting the image of the US government through worldwide press publicity of US War Crimes.

Hence the additional question:

**Q. Did the Russell Tribunal on War Crimes in Vietnam attempt to hold hearings in the most appropriate place - that is the USA? If so, how did the USA respond?**

Going by the preceding, I see that they tried to undermine the moral authority of the tribunal through the press (and most likely other channels).

However, this should not have stopped the tribunal attempting to set up a session in the US itself - which is, perhaps, where it was most required.

I don't see this as a question of politics but of legal history. But I see that there is no such tag.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would be more appropriate for Politics.SE or History.SE (I'm not sure which), but it is an interesting question

Answer (score 0):

> Was Russell's call instrumental in helping to set up the International Criminal Court at The Hague?

**No**

The [ICC](https://www.beyondintractability.org/essay/int_war_crime_tribunals) is a direct result of the recognition of the need for a permanent body rather than the ad-hoc system that had been in place before 2002. Particularly the War Crimes Tribunals for the former [Yugoslavia](https://www.icty.org) and [Rwanda](https://unictr.irmct.org/en/tribunal) in the 1990s.

> Did the Russell Tribunal on War Crimes in Vietnam attempt to hold hearings in the most appropriate place - that is the USA? If so, how did the USA respond?

I don’t know but since this was a political action rather than a legal one, the question belongs on politics.